# I have a question regarding wordpress hook and filter

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I would like to replace some text with photo in Buddypress welcome email.
I'm new to Wordpress and filter.

```
<?php
do_action( 'bp_before_email_header' );
echo bp_get_option( 'blogname' );
do_action( 'bp_after_email_header' );
?>
```

I add a code on function.php like this:

```
add_action( 'bp_before_email_header', 'add_logo');
function add_logo() {
    echo '<img src="photo url"';
}
```

There's a photo in email header, however, I would like to remove the text bp_get_option( 'blogname' ); 
If there's no apply filter, I can not modify it without editing it directly?
How can I do that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bp_get_option has a filter. [Check Code](http://hookr.io/functions/bp_get_option/). You need simply apply this filter like that for example.

```
add_filter('bp_get_option', function($value) {
    if ($value == 'blogname') {
       return '';
    }

    return $value;
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, will not it affect anything else? I am afraid that it affects other functions that use bp_get_option( 'blogname' );

Comment: Good question. You can add this filter inside `bp_before_email_header` action so it would be fired only when email header is called.

Comment: Thank you so much @Artem :) I see. The final codes looks like this as you taught me:
add_action( 'bp_before_email_header', 'add_logo');
function add_logo() {
    echo '<img src="photo url"';
add_filter('bp_get_option', function($value) {
    if ($value == 'blogname') {
       return '';
    }

    return $value;
}, 10);
}

Comment: It's a stupid question, but since I'm a beginner in php, the number 10 is the default value so  Is it okay to remove the number "10" in add_filter?

Comment: Yes, you can remove "10"  just make sure you remove and comma "," before :)